# PHP - use imagejpeg as background

Tags: php

I have loaded an image in a variable like this :

```
$img = imagecreatefromjpeg('my_image.jpg');
```

Now I want to use that image variable as a background for an html element. I tried this :

```
<div id="container" style="background:<?php imagejpeg($img);?>;"></div>
```

And I failed miserably. I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: Post the result of imagejpeg($img);

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what's your ultimate goal, but why not do something like this:

```
$img = my_image.jpg;
<div id="container" style="background-image: url(<?=$img?>);"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think u failed because your code leaks an 'echo' statement:

```
<div id="container" style="background:<?php echo imagejpeg($img);?>;"</div>
```

should do the work :-)

Comment: Have you verified that the path for the image is correct? Also, try vieweing the HTML source code to see if the `image path` is getting set correctly inside your html `style=background` tag.